# String into Object[][] Java

Tags: java, string, object, converters

I have a string like this

```
String data = vini,vidi,vici
```

and I want to make it into object[][] like this

```
Object[][] user = new Object[][] {{"vini"}, {"vidi"}, {"vici"}};
```

If there is any way to solve this, please suggest. thankyou.

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at the `String` API that might have a method that will help

Comment: Yes, there is a way to solve this. --- [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: If that is what you want, then you should start coding. I would suggest you start by making that first statement syntactically valid, so it will actually compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String data = "vini,vidi,vici";
String[] rows = data.split(",");

Object[][] matrix = new Object[rows.length][]; 
int i = 0;
for (String row : rows)
   matrix[i++] = row.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Just split the given `String` using `String.split()` at comma delimiter `","` which converts into a `1D` array `rows` of type `String` like: `[vini, vidi, vici]`. Create a `2D` array of type `Object`, iterate in rows and start filling the string values in the array per row after splitting again at the comma delimiter. Print the `matrix` using `Arrays.deepToString()` method.

```
Output: [[vini], [vidi], [vici]]
```

Hope it answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String's method `split`, that will return an array.

Then loop the returned string and save each array element in the Object's one.

```
 String data = "veni, vidi, vici";
 String splittedData = data.split(", ");
 Object[][] user = new Object[splittedData.length][1];
 for(int i = 0; i < splittedData.length; i++) {
    user[i][0] = splittedData[i];
 }
```